# I can't change main Django project settings file

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-settings

I was trying to configure the Django Database Settings to use mysql.
I followed the instructions provided [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-or-mariadb-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I started a Django project within the myproject directory.

```
django-admin.py startproject myproject .
```

I tried to open the main Django project settings file

```
nano ~/myproject/myproject/settings.py
```

And the terminal did not display a DATABASES section at the bottom of this file. Instead I had `^G Get Help  ^O WriteOut  ^R Read File ^Y Prev Page ^K Cut Text  ^C Cur Pos
^X Exit      ^J Justify   ^W Where Is  ^V Next Page ^U UnCut Text^T To Spell`

What do you recommend? I need to change this settings file to use mysql database.I have Ubuntu 14.04. and python 3.4. installed.

Comment: `^G Get Help  ^O WriteOut...` ***is*** `nano`'s UI. Either you're opening the wrong file and are getting a blank editor, or you aren't properly using `nano` to locate the section labeled `DATABASES`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reasons for your problem:

1. This is not the correct path: `~/myproject/myproject/settings.py`.
2. Path is correct but you are facing issue using **`nano`**. Try using **`vim`** instead (if you are familiar with it). If not, try using any **GUI** editor.

As you already mentioned, you are on **Ubuntu** -- open the terminal and type **`gedit`** to open the text editor. Now navigate to the settings file on your system.

Comment: Ah, great! I'm glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, `nano` is a terminal editor. Your mouse won't work. You'll have to use the cursor arrows to get down to the `DATABASES` section. Hold down the down cursor arrow for 30 seconds and see what happens.

After you make changes, hit `Cntrl+X` to save your changes and exit.